# Is the complexity of $\binom{2n}{n} = O(2^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

How to find the complexity of $f(n)=\binom{2n}{n}$?

We know that $f(n)=\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.

Is this $O(n^2)$? What concerns me is $n!$

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on the [Central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Comment: $\frac{2^n}{n!}$ is $O(2^n)$ much in the same way as it is $O(2^{2^{2^{n!}}})$ (big O means it's an asymptotic upper bound, not necessarily tight). But $2^n$ is not $O(\frac{2^n}{n!}).$ In fact, $\frac{2^n}{n!}\to 0.$ But this is irrelevant since the equality ${2n \choose n}= \frac{2^n}{n!}$ has no basis in reality.

Comment: We can estimate ${2n \choose n}$ using a Gaussian approximation since this divided by $2^{2n}$ is the probability of getting exactly half heads when you flip a coin $2n$ times. The variance is $\frac{2n}{4},$ so this probability is about $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi  n}}$ so we have an estimate of $\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$ (Alternatively, appeal to Stirling's formula, using the fact that ${2n\choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.)

Comment: These answers are really valuable. Thanks to both of you! So, based on the Guassian estimation we could say that $\binom{2n}{n}$ is $O(4^n)$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you know that:

$\begin{align*}
2^{2 n}
  &=    (1 + 1)^{2 n}  \\
  &=    \sum_{0 \le k \le 2 n} \binom{2 n}{k} \\
  &\ge \binom{2 n}{n}
\end{align*}$

so that $\binom{2 n}{n} = O(2^{2 n})$.

More precise estimates are from Stirling's approximation, in the variant given by Robbins ("A Remark on Stirling's Formula", AMM 62:1 (1955), 26-29):

$\begin{align*}
&n!
   = \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \cdot e^{r(n)} \\
&\frac{1}{12 n + 1} < r(n) < \frac{1}{12 n}
\end{align*}$

We have:

$\begin{align*}
\binom{2 n}{n}
  &= \frac{(2 n)!}{(n!)^2} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\cdot 2^{2 n} \cdot e^{r(2 n) - 2 r(n)} \\
\end{align*}$

This means that:

$\begin{align*}
\binom{2 n}{n}
  = \Theta\left(2^{2 n} \cdot n^{-1/2}\right)
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 2):

The [OEIS sequence A000984](https://oeis.org/A000984) "Central binomial coefficients" contains the line

> Using Stirling's formula in $A000142$ it is easy to get the asymptotic expression $a(n) \sim 4^n / \sqrt{\pi  n}.$

which implies that $a(n) := \binom{2n}{n} = O(4^n).$
The Wikipedia article [Central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) has this expression also using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) formula and this implies that the sequence is **not** of polynomial growth rate.